# Call a child class method from a parent class object

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following classes

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    void getName(){...}}

class Student extends Person{
    String class;
    void getClass(){...}
}

class Teacher extends Person{
    String experience;
    void getExperience(){...}
}
```

This is just a simplified version of my actual schema. Initially I don't know the type of person that needs to be created, so the function that handles the creation of these objects takes the general `Person` object as a parameter.

```
void calculate(Person p){...}
```

Now I want to access the methods of the child classes using this parent class object. I also need to access parent class methods from time to time so **I CANNOT MAKE IT ABSTRACT**.

---

I guess I simplified too much in the above example, so here goes , this is the actual structure.

```
class Question {
  // private attributes
  :
  private QuestionOption option;
  // getters and setters for private attributes
  :
  public QuestionOption getOption(){...}
 }

 class QuestionOption{
 ....
 }
 class ChoiceQuestionOption extends QuestionOption{
 private boolean allowMultiple;
 public boolean getMultiple(){...}
 }

 class Survey{
  void renderSurvey(Question q) {
      /*
          Depending on the type of question (choice, dropdwn or other, I have to render
          the question on the UI. The class that calls this doesnt have compile time 
          knowledge of the type of question that is going to be rendered. Each question 
          type has its own rendering function. If this is for choice , I need to access 
          its functions using q. 
      */
      if(q.getOption().getMultiple())
        {...}
  }
 }
```

The if statement says "cannot find getMultiple for QuestionOption." OuestionOption has many more child classes that have different types of methods that are not common among the children (getMultiple is not common among the children)

Comment: Do you have any common abstraction in mind? You need to find a way to represent the specifics of each subclass in a joint concept. Then you'll be able to define a method in `Person` that you override in subclasses with appropriate behavior.

Comment: For example, what are you calculating? Why don't you implement the `calculate` method in each subclass?

Comment: And what is that Person parameter to `calculate`? If that is the target of the calculation, maybe it should be `calculate()` and then do something with `this` instead (which will work great with overriding methods in subclasses).

Comment: This question needs more info - its incomplete. Please show exactly what youre trying to do and what syntax errors you're seeing!

Comment: class is a reserved word in java, you must use another name for the Student's attribute

Comment: @amicngh Haha.. sorry, Im new to this forum. All I seem to be able to do is vote up an answer. How do you accept an answer anyway ?

Comment: @user1349663  read the link http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask. it is mention how to upvote and accept an answer..

Comment: How can you have in Student the method void getClass() ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

***NOTE:*** Though this is possible, it is not at all recommended as it kind of destroys the reason for inheritance. The best way would be to restructure your application design so that there are **NO** parent to child dependencies. A parent should not ever need to know its children or their capabilities.

However.. you should be able to do it like:

```
void calculate(Person p) {
    ((Student)p).method();
}
```

a safe way would be:

```
void calculate(Person p) {
    if(p instanceof Student) ((Student)p).method();
}
```

Comment: Yes! And shouldn't be done if avoidable. But you can do this if you absolutely cannot avoid calling a method from a child class from parent class code..

Comment: What makes you think that it  absolutely cannot be avoided here?

Comment: +1 for a good answer. It would be better though if you also pointed out that this is a bad way to go, and OP would be better off rethinking his class hierarchy.

Comment: @Keppil then is not a good answer. It is just a way to work around a bad design.

Comment: Yes, definitely not the way to go, but i was only trying to point out a possible option.. BTW, have added the warning note to the answer..

Comment: @Matteo: I disagree. Since what OP is asking is doable I think techfoobar deserves credit for showing how it is done in a clear way. Since I thought an advice should be added I added my comment.

Comment: @Keppil OP wants help on OOP design, it is clear from his question.

Comment: @Keppil almost everything is doable, but this does not mean that by solving his problem we are really helping him. A bad design has consequences, in my opinion we should help to have a clean design.

Comment: I agree with both of you that we should help, which I think is accomplished by the note. I still think it is useful to tell OP that it is doable and how it is done, even if it rarely, if ever, should be used.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid giving Student class in calculate() method ? (I have a lot of classes and I want to make a generic calculate() method)

Comment: A protocol is defining that a class needs to have certain functions in them.  And a class can both inherit from a parent class and have a protocol state that certain functions need to be present.   Seems like there are some potential solutions where one might want to do this.  And it might allow for reusing code in a way that might not be completely possible otherwise.

Answer (score 15):

A parent class should not have knowledge of child classes. You can implement a method `calculate()` and override it in every subclass:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    void getName(){...}
    void calculate();
}
```

and then

```
class Student extends Person{
    String class;
    void getClass(){...}

    @Override
    void calculate() {
        // do something with a Student
    }
}
```

and

```
class Teacher extends Person{
    String experience;
    void getExperience(){...}

    @Override
    void calculate() {
        // do something with a Teacher
    }

}
```

By the way. Your statement about abstract classes is confusing. You can call methods defined in an abstract class, but of course only of instances of subclasses.

In your example you can make `Person` abstract and the use `getName()` on instanced of `Student` and `Teacher`.

Comment: is `// do something with a Teacher` instead of `// do something with a Student` in the second example?

Answer (score 4):

Many of the answers here are suggesting implementing variant types using "Classical Object-Oriented Decomposition".  That is, anything which might be needed on one of the variants has to be declared at the base of the hierarchy.  I submit that this is a type-safe, but often very bad, approach.  You either end up exposing all internal properties of all the different variants (most of which are "invalid" for each particular variant) or you end up cluttering the API of the hierarchy with tons of procedural methods (which means you have to recompile every time a new procedure is dreamed up).

I hesitate to do this, but here is a shameless plug for a blog post I wrote that outlines about 8 ways to do variant types in Java.  They all suck, because Java sucks at variant types.  So far the only JVM language that gets it right is Scala.

http://jazzjuice.blogspot.com/2010/10/6-things-i-hate-about-java-or-scala-is.html

The Scala creators actually wrote a paper about three of the eight ways.  If I can track it down, I'll update this answer with a link.

**UPDATE**: found it [here](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~emir/written/MatchingObjectsWithPatterns-TR.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just write an empty method in Person and override it in the children classes? And call it, when it needs to be:

```
void caluculate(Person p){
  p.dotheCalculate();
}
```

This would mean you have to have the same method in both children classes, but i don't see why this would be a problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation and I found a way around with a bit of engineering as follows - -

1. You have to have your method in parent class without any parameter and use - -

   ```
   Class<? extends Person> cl = this.getClass(); // inside parent class
   ```
2. Now, with 'cl' you can access all child class fields with their name and  initialized values by using - -

   ```
   cl.getDeclaredFields(); cl.getField("myfield"); // and many more
   ```
3. In this situation your 'this' pointer will reference your child class object if you are calling parent method through your child class object.
4. Another thing you might need to use is Object obj = cl.newInstance();

Let me know if still you got stucked somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Car extends Vehicle {
        protected int numberOfSeats = 1;

        public int getNumberOfSeats() {
            return this.numberOfSeats;

        }

        public void  printNumberOfSeats() {
          //  return this.numberOfSeats;
            System.out.println(numberOfSeats);
        }


    } 

//Parent class

  class Vehicle {
        protected String licensePlate = null;

        public void setLicensePlate(String license) {
            this.licensePlate = license;
            System.out.println(licensePlate);
        }


   public static void main(String []args) {
       Vehicle c = new Vehicle();

      c.setLicensePlate("LASKF12341"); 

//Used downcasting to call the child method from the parent class. 
//Downcasting = It’s the casting from a superclass to a subclass.

      Vehicle d = new Car();
      ((Car) d).printNumberOfSeats();


   }
   }
```

Comment: Hello, welcome in Stack Overflow. Try to add more comments (not in code) that will explain author why you think that this is answer that he/she is looking for. Code-only answer is not very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be

```
class Survey{
  void renderSurvey(Question q) {
  /*
      Depending on the type of question (choice, dropdwn or other, I have to render
      the question on the UI. The class that calls this doesnt have compile time 
      knowledge of the type of question that is going to be rendered. Each question 
      type has its own rendering function. If this is for choice , I need to access 
      its functions using q. 
  */
  if(q.getOption() instanceof ChoiceQuestionOption)
  {
    ChoiceQuestionOption choiceQuestion = (ChoiceQuestionOption)q.getOption();
    boolean result = choiceQuestion.getMultiple();
    //do something with result......
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read somewhere that instanceof was one of those minefields that lead to a lot of bugs. What should I take care of while coding if I use this ?

Comment: Yes, Its generally not a good OO practice to have many `instanceof` in a class but it should not lead to any bugs until you have duplicate class/interface names or you are loading it through different class loaders..