# Calling method from java child class not in parent class

Tags: java, polymorphism

Consider the following base/derived classes:

```
public class Car {
    private int cylinders;

    public Car(int cyl) {
        cylinders = cyl;
    }

    public int getCylinders() {
        return cylinders;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SportsCar extends Car  {
    private int topSpeed;

    public SportsCar(int cyl, int top) {
        super(cyl);
        topSpeed = top;
    }

    public int getTopSpeed() {
        return topSpeed;
    }
}
```

Now, consider the following two objects:

```
    SportsCar lambo = new SportsCar(8,255);
    Car m5 = new SportsCar(10,240);
```

The following method call compiles fine:

```
lambo.getTopSpeed();
```

However this method call breaks with the error "cannot find symbol -  method getTopSpeed()"

```
m5.getTopSpeed();
```

Now I understand that the `getTopSpeed` method must exist in the base class in order for it to compile since `m5` is a `Car` type, so if I include `getTopSpeed` in `Car` then `m5.getTopSpeed();` compiles nicely.

My questions are:

1. Why does the error "cannot find symbol -  method getTopSpeed()" happen at compile time and not run time?
2. Why doesn't "late binding" prevent this error?
3. Assuming `getTopSpeed` is implemented in `Car` (so it compiles) when the program is run, does the compiler first check to see if `getTopSpeed` exists in `Car` and then checks to see if it is over-ridden in `SportsCar` or does it just "know" that it is over-ridden already from the compiler and directly uses the over-ridden method?

Comment: Your first question [can reasonably be answered with the first sentence](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11466790/1079354) in this other question's answer.  The other bits, I'd encourage a bit of a perusal of the JLS.

Comment: `m5` is a reference variable of type `Car`, which means you can only invoke methods defined in `Car`. If you would like to use the methods in `SportsCar`, you must explicitly cast `m5` as a `SportsCar`.

Comment: The compiler cannot "see" the members of a derived type through a variable of a parent type. There are two types involved, the declared type of the _variable_ that the compiler works with, and the runtime type of the _object_ that the JVM works with. You were expecting the compiler to process the _variable_ as if it could see the runtime type of the _object_. It can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Java is statically typed language, so a variable type should be known at compile time. If type that is known to the compiler doesn't expose such a method - it is compilation failure. Exactly for the reason to not let it to runtime.
2. Why should it? It just finds the method body late, not signature. Still, static typing means that signature must be satisfied at compile time.
3. At runtime JVM tries to find the most specific implementation. In SportsCar, in your case. If it is inherited from parent but absent in child - parent's code is used.

If you need to call method from specific child which is absent in variable type - you can cast it at runtime at your own risk of getting ClassCastException.

Comment: Or instead of casting, if you need the child type then simply declare the variable as the child type. Casting is code smell.

Comment: Well, it depends. Yes, it increases risk of runtime exception. But, on the other hand, if you know what you are doing - it can be ok. How about Akka/Java style of pattern matching on message types, for example?

Comment: It's still code smell. In the great majority of cases where I've seen `instanceof` used, it's to work around a gap in the type analysis.

Comment: ...or implementing equals method? Of course, as long as you can avoid it - that's great.

Comment: Implementing `equals` is an example of working around a gap in the type analysis.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But if that is a code smell - there should be some "true" way of doing things. Casting int to byte or char is another example of such unavoidable evil. Passing around parameters of type Class. I believe, we can find many such examples. Or is that sort of language smell? Quite holywarish topic...

Comment: "It just finds the method body late, not signature." clarified everything.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when the compiler sees this:

```
SportsCar lambo = new SportsCar(8,255);
Car m5 = new SportsCar(10,240);
```

It knows lambo is a SportsCar, but only knows m5 is a Car. If you want get the top speed for m5, you'll have to cast it to a SportsCar first:

```
((SportsCar)m5).getTopSpeed();
```

Most of the time I've seen casting, however, the variable is cast to another variable first:

```
SportsCar sportsM5 = (SportsCar)m5;
sportsM5.getTopSpeed();
```

[This aspect of polymorphism in Java confused me once when I was passing an object to a method.](http://hendrixjoseph.github.io/polymorphism/)