# Why h.print_for() gives error message while g.print_for() working just fine?

Tags: java

```
class one {

    public void print_geek(){
        System.out.println("Geeks");
    }
}
```

```
class two extends one {

    public void print_for() { 
        System.out.println("for"); 
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        two g = new two();
        one h = g;
        g.print_geek();
        h.print_for();
        g.print_geek();
    }
}
```

While trying to run the above code I am getting error:

```
"error: cannot find symbol
        h.print_for();
         ^
  symbol:   method print_for()
  location: variable h of type one "
```

Despite h and g being same object. I having hard time understanding what is the issue here?

Comment: Same object but not the same variable. The Java compiler sees that `h` is `one` type and thus only has methods of `one` available to it (unless it is cast). This gets down to the basic difference between variables and objects. This also makes sense since you can re-assign `h` later to be a `one` instance.

Comment: Please also look at this Q&A: [Calling method from java child class not in parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562916/calling-method-from-java-child-class-not-in-parent-class)

Comment: but this works if i change the name of method of class one from print_geek to print_for(). And then when i run the code it displays the statment of print_for() from class two i.e "for"

Comment: Exactly -- and you should be able to figure out why this is so

Comment: This is due to polymorphism, the h object for the g but casted as an object of the one class, if you want to get the original g, I think you should call it this way (Two)g and call the method

Comment: @WhiteReve as is well-discussed in the 2nd duplicate Q&A