# How to access a Child class function in java

Tags: java, class, methods, parent

Let's say this is my parent class:

```
public class Person {
}
```

Here is my child class:

```
public class Manager extends Person{
    public String department = 'Meat';

    public String getDepartment(){
        return department;
    }
}
```

Here's my main file:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Person[] myPeople = new Person[2];

    myPeople[0] = new Manager();
}
```

So, here's my question: Is there any way that I can access to this getDepartment() method from the myPeople array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a child class method from a parent class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466441/call-a-child-class-method-from-a-parent-class-object)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466441/call-a-child-class-method-from-a-parent-class-object

please check the above question

Comment: The warning in the [answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11466495/2513200) does not apply to the same extent in your case, as you do this in `manin` and not in the parent class `Person`. The solution - `instanceof` check followed by cast - is the same.

Comment: You have to down cast Ex: `((Manager )p).getDepartment();` safest way is `if(p instanceof Manager ) ((Manager )p).getDepartment();`